# Conflict in "Promise" while setting up new project using Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015

```
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.6\lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts(203,11): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.6\lib.es2015.promise.d.ts(223,13): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.6\lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(168,11): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.6\lib.es5.d.ts(1292,11): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>c:\users\username\node_modules@types\es6-promise\index.d.ts(11,15): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
1>c:\users\username\node_modules@types\es6-promise\index.d.ts(42,19): error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'Promise'.
```

tsconfig: -

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"noStrictGenericChecks": true
}
}
```

Package.Json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.6.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

npm 5.5.1
node 8.9.1

Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to tsConfig file

> `"skipLibCheck": true`